# ESLint: '<anyLibrary>' should be listed in the project's dependencies

Tags: react-native, intellij-idea, eslint

ESLint is complaining about each imported library. The libraries, however, are installed and listed in the package.json dependencies. And I am using them without any problems. Here is the error message from one out of many libraries:

> ESLint: 'react-native-gesture-handler' should be listed in the
> project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S react-native-gesture-handler' to
> add it(import/no-extraneous-dependencies)

Here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "SmartphoneApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.4.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "i18n-js": "^4.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.11",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.21.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.11",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.10",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Here is eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "react-native/react-native": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb",
        "airbnb/hooks",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "react-native"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-use-before-define": ["error", { "variables": false }],
        "global-require": 0,
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,
        "import/prefer-default-export": "off"
    }
}
```

Here are ESLint settings in IntelliJ IDEA:
I use automatic settings as following:
[image]

But switching to manual as this does not make a difference:
[image]

What did I configure wrong? Please help.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue. I am getting this for my project as well and I am not able to solve it

Comment: @Hardik3296 At the end I reinstalled everything using some guide I found on the internet and it fixed the problem. But unfortunately I do not remember which guide I used, that was a year ago.